# Will 'AggregateRating' of a 'Service' show star rating in Google SERP?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Would below code show star rating with SERP result in Google?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
                            Horoscope 2018          </span>
            Overall rating:         <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                <strong><span class="value" itemprop="ratingValue">
                    4.7             </span></strong> out of
                <strong><span itemprop="bestRating">5</span></strong> based on
                <span class="votes" itemprop="reviewCount">
                    26              </span> reviews.
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: What makes you think that it wouldn’t? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I added a missing opening `<span>` tag in the second line of your code and it validated on the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), so I think it's reasonable to conclude that it's eligible to show in Google SERP results.

Eligible isn't a guarantee that it will show though, Google is going to consider other factors as well.

Good luck!
[image]